# Calibre "UnicodeDecodeError" when attempting to convert a PDF to EPUB; tex4ebook also failed

Tags: pdf, epub

When attempting to convert a PDF to EPUB, Calibre halts with UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 1209: invalid continuation byte.

I created the PDF with Debian 10; the file opens and displays with evince and with Calibre.  There is no math and no illustrations; the file is a text-only Bible study.  I created a LaTeX class file based on article.cls, because I needed to alter the quotation environment.

I tried to use tex4ebook, but it complained about the .cls file.  Calibre conversion failed with a PDF created by pdflatex and with a PDF created with ps2pdf.

Comment: The *UnicodeDecodeError* has nothing to do with LaTeX, but is related to Python not being able to read the file as UTF-8 (Calibre might use Python there).

Comment: I discarded my custom .cls and reverted to article.cls.  That made the error go away, even in tex4ebook.  But now the layout is so ugly that I may offer only pdf.  Also, the output of tex4ebook looks much nicer than the output of calibre.

Comment: You will probably need to write a configuration file for tex4ebook if you use a custom class. Could you update your question. With a MWE? It cannot be answered without more information.